# Solr: Define type in schema file for data value as FilePath

Tags: solr

I want to upload FilePath in SOLR data folder and search it via my website using LIKE operation.

for that i tried using the following types in schema file but was in unsuccessful.

Try 1.

```
<fieldType name="string_wildcards" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.ISOLatin1AccentFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="30"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.ISOLatin1AccentFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Try2. Using Letter Tokeniser.

```
  <fieldType name="string_wildcards_letter" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
          <analyzer type="index">
              <tokenizer class="solr.LetterTokenizerFactory"/>
              <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
              <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="30"/>
          </analyzer>
          <analyzer type="query">
              <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
              <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
              <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          </analyzer>
      </fieldType>
```

Try 3. Using Keyword Tokeniser.

```
<fieldType name="string_wildcards_keyword" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
              <analyzer type="index">
                  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
                  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                  <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="30"/>
              </analyzer>
              <analyzer type="query">
                  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
                  <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
                  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
              </analyzer>
          </fieldType>
```

All the above three try's were unsuccessful. Anybodies help would be appreciated.

SOLR Query Example

```
Field Name: 
OriginalFilePath

My Input value is:
X:\Intake\1102\02.01.11\TX_DA26396_RushTopCompanies_Non-SERFF_01.28.11_PR\TX_P_1_01.28.11_NS\Dairyland County Mutual Insurance Company_01.28.11 03.pdf

My Query is:
OriginalFilePath:(x\\:\\\\intake\\\\1102\\\\02.01.11\\\\tx_da26396_rushtopcompanies_non\\-serff_01.28.11_pr\\\\tx_p_1_01.28.11_ns\\\\dairyland county mutual insurance company_01.28.11 03.p*)
```

Last astrieks is for using LIKE operation on that field.

Please let me know if any thing is wrong in my query formation as well.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use a wildcard search. You can find a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229286/wildcard-search-in-solr

Answer (score 0):

You can check on [PathHierarchyTokenizer](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-PathHierarchyTokenizer) which will split the paths and help you execute wildcard queries.

You can also probably use [RegularExpressionPatternTokenizer](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-RegularExpressionPatternTokenizer) and generate tokens on the delimiter.
You would end up with individual tokens (and not file path hierarchy) which can be used with wildcard query